# Does the Galaxy Far Far Away have a name?

Tags: star-wars

The galaxy we live in has a name: The Milky Way.  Does the galaxy where Star Wars takes place have a name?

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately it's already been asked and answered elsewhere on the site!

Comment: PS The name "Milky Way" means exactly the same as "Galaxy". (One is a translation, the other a transliteration, of the Greek "Γαλαξίας").